# Why is Luke Skywalker's nickname "Wormie"?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

When speaking to his friends in various deleted scenes, we learn that Luke's friends refer to him as "Wormie".

Long considered to be merely a 'Legend' this nickname was mentioned (and canonised) by the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook.

**What I can't tell is why his nickname was "*Wormie*"?**

Does he display some especially worm-like tendencies or personality traits? Is it a reference to some part of his physique or anatomy?

Comment: "Whiney Wormie"?

Comment: Wait, the original novel is not considered canon?

Comment: He popularized "the worm" dance move that quickly became the rave cross Tatooine.

Comment: Actually, in the original novel, "Wormie" only appears twice, both times spoken by Carnie, so we only know of one friend who calls him that. It might be just that she alone uses that nickname for him. In that same scene, others call him "Luke" and Biggs calls him "hotshot".

Comment: I wonder whether that might have been George Lucas's nickname....

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Perhaps Carnie knows something we don't...

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Elements of the novelisations that refer to deleted scenes are considered to be "legends" and hence non-canon.

Comment: And I suppose elements of the novelizations that refer to never-filmed scenes are also legends. Bizaare.

Comment: @Jonah That brings up a question I've assumed I knew the answer to but now I realize I was just assuming: Do moisture farmers harvest water, or do they use vaporators to collect moisture for actual crops that they grow? I.e., is their crop moisture, or is moisture used to grow their crop?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'm reasonably sure they collect the water and sell it.

Comment: That's what I always thought. I feel like that's what is described in *The Star Wars Storybook*, which would explain why I always interpreted it that way.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47796/how-exactly-does-one-farm-moisture

Comment: That means Jonah's supposition doesn't hold water. Ha ha.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Not so fast! What if the water isn't sanitized, and contains parasitic worms?

Comment: @Jonah - I'd strongly prefer Canon, but if there's a Legends reason, I'd be more than happy to hear about it.

Comment: He had an unfortunate predilection for helicoptering at the most ill-chosen and unflattering times.

Comment: Related, not dupe:  Why is Richard's name @Valorum?

Comment: @WadCheber - Suffered a devestating vote of no confidence, deserted in his hour of need by those who he thought were supporting him.

Comment: FYI: Video link is dead

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Even Luke doesn't know

Mentions of "Wormie" Luke Skywalker, both canon and Legends, are rather sparse.

In the [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html), the name "Wormie" appears only a handful of times, always spoken by Luke's friend Camie:

> FIXER:
>                            Did I hear a young noise blast through 
>                            here?
>
> CAMIE:
>                            It was just wormie on another rampage.

Similarly:

> LUKE:
>                            Hey, easy with those...
>
> CAMIE:
>                            Don't worry about it, Wormie.

A search of 270+ Legends novels reveals only two mentions of "Wormie," and all instances of its variant "Wormy" are simply descriptive.

In other material, we see that Camie is not the only one to call Luke Wormie.

This is true in canon:

[image]

And in Legends, we know Fixer does:

> Luke looked back at Fixer. "What?" Luke said. "Me?"
>
> Fixer leered at
>   him. "What, are you scared, Wormie?"
>
> —*The Life of Luke Skywalker*

As does Windy:

> "Miss me, Windy?" Luke asked, grinning.
>
> "Missed beating you at holopool," a burly young man said, chuckling as
>   he drove a knuckle into Luke's shoulder. He dragged Luke over to the
>   table, pounding him on the back.
>
> "Skywalker's back!" he announced. "All hail the conquering Wormie!"
>
> The group burst into a mocking cheer.
>
> —*Star Wars: Rebel Force: Renegade*

As an aside, this does show that it was a mocking nickname even in-universe.

In Legends, though, we know a *tiny* bit more— that Camie was the one who came up with the title "Wormie," and **that even Luke is uncertain how he got that nickname!**

> Huh," Luke said, as if he couldn't care less. He did his best not to
>   think about Camie, **who'd encouraged the others to call him Wormie, and
>   for no good reason that he could think of**.
>
> —*The Life of Luke Skywalker*

The out-of-universe reason was undoubtedly to show Luke's unpopularity with the local kids, but even Luke may not know the in-universe reason.

Comment: +1 for the quote from "The Life of Luke Skywalker". It's not canon, but at least it explicitly explains it.

Answer (score 23):

## According to Mark Hamill, it's simply a negative term intended to show he "wasn't well-liked" by his friends.

From an interview with *Rolling Stone Magazine*:

> **MARK HAMILL:** There was a scene at the beginning of the first movie that was cut out. When you're first introduced to [Luke], he's on the farm, and he sees the robots, when R2 and C3PO eject he races to the club, and you see what his life is like on Tataouine [sic]. **This beautiful actress calls him 'wormy.' I loved it [because] you saw that he wasn't well liked by his peers**, and he bumps into Garrick Hagon, and Luke is really excited because he has joined the Empire, and Luke is so anxious to get off the farm and find his lot in life. He's thrilled that Biggs has joined the Empire, and feels as soon as he'd get the chance he'd join the rebel alliance. This shows that Luke is apolitical, and joining the empire is even attractive to him. They changed to get to the plot faster, so now it goes straight to the fourth scene.

([Source](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/mark-hamill-reveals-luke-skywalkers-favorite-lightsaber-20140122#ixzz48ZMRSmrM))

I can't find anything specifically tying the nickname to physical traits in-universe, although one might surmise that his friends would choose it in response to his youth and scrawniness at the time.  Regardless, it carries the intended effect of showing him to be the *least likely* person in the estimations of his friends to go on to be a galactic hero.

Comment: Hmm. It shows that his nickname is offensive but it doesn't show *why* it's his nickname.

Comment: It's also not exactly in-universe.

Comment: @Richard : I speculated on the "why" (in-universe).   I can't find an official explanation regarding Luke's physique and the nickname "wormie", but it seems to be pretty on-the-nose.

Comment: So, basically, Luke is the dweeb pestering the "cool kids."

Answer (score 1):

Only one person calls him wormy. The others in the scene treat him better. The woman who calls him Wormy also yanks his binoculars out of his hands so she can use them. Then she shoves the binoculars back at him and walks off without considering Luke as anything more than "the man that holds the binoculars".

As far we know, only one person uses that nickname for him. Her words and actions probably say more about her than about Luke. Which means her nickname for him could have nothing to do with his tendencies, personality traits, or anatomy. She clearly does not respect his boundaries.

In a later scene, Biggs treats him with respect and even kindness. They joke together. They are comfortable with each other. They trust each other. They like each other. They are affectionate.

We know very little about Luke's friends and his relationships with them, so any answer beyond Mark Hamill's interview is speculative.

Comment: It's not only Carrie that calls him "Wormie". At least according to the (disney canon) comic serial; http://i.stack.imgur.com/9mKEW.png

Answer (score 1):

I have done some googling but can't find anything about the origin of the nick name, only that, that is what he was called by his friends -

> Skywalker cultivated a group of like-minded friends on Tatooine, amongst whom he earned the nickname "Wormie." The group included Deak, Windy, Camie Loneozner and Fixer, whose horizons did not extend much past Tatooine itself; and "Tank" and Biggs Darklighter, who shared Skywalker's dreams of joining the Imperial Academy and becoming pilots.

(warning spoilers on site)

[[source-1]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker/Legends)

I have found a number of other places that mention this being is nickname but the all just repeat the same information without clarification on the where and why's of *how* he got it.

[[Source-2]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker)

[[source-3]](http://www.t-rob.com/swgw.htm)

Comment: Those links might have been better as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

George has often stated that a big influence on Episode IV was Arthurian legend. In Arthurian legend, specifically The Once and Future King and Sword in the Stone, Arthur is called Wart/the Wart for almost the entirety of the story, and isn’t addressed as Arthur until the very end, when he is crowned King of England.

George talks about how Anakin’s lightsaber is the equivalent to Excalibur. It’s why the Obi-Wan and Vader fight was kinda weak compared to the rest of the trilogy; he intended for the laser swords to weigh as much as a long-sword once ignited.

I think calling Luke “Wormie” was just yet another reference/homage to the origins of King Arthur. This is entirely speculative on my part, and not an in-universe explanation, but I honestly think there isn’t one. It was just tacked on as another reference to King Arthur, IMO.

Comment: Backing this up with quotes and references would improve it.